# Call to a member function saveSibling() on a non-object?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, dynamic

i added the code to add the row dynamically to the form and when user submit the form it will call the function(saveSibling) of the application object that will save the data into the database(Sibling table)but it doesnt work. when all data has been submitted user will be redirected to updateAppplication.php

```html
$userID = $_SESSION['username'];
 $a = new application();
 $nameSib = $jobSib = $relationshipSib  = $jabatan = $age = $statusSib = "";
 
 $check = true;
 
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
 { 
  //save n cont to next form
    if(isset($_POST['saveContinue']))
    {
   $nameSib = $_POST['nameSib'];
   $jobSib = $_POST['jobSib'];
   $relationshipSib = $_POST['relationshipSib'];
   $jabatan = $_POST['jabatan'];
   $age = $_POST['age'];
   $statusSib = $_POST['statusSib'];
    
   foreach($nameSib as $a => $b)
   {
    if(isset($_POST['nameSib']) && isset($_POST['relationshipSib']) && isset($_POST['age']) && isset($_POST['statusSib']) || isset($_POST['jobSib']) || isset($_POST['jabatan']))
     $a -> saveSibling($userID, $nameSib[$a], $relationshipSib[$a], $age[$a], $statusSib[$a], $jobSib[$a], $jabatan[$a]);
   }
   header('Location: displayApplication.php');
   
  }
  
 }
```

```html
public function saveSibling($studID, $nameSib,  $relationshipSib, $age, $statusSib, $jobSib, $jabatan)
 {
  $this -> studID = $studID;
  $this -> nameSib = $nameSib;
  $this -> jobSib = $jobSib;
  $this -> relationshipSib = $relationshipSib;
  $this -> age = $age;
  $this -> statusSib = $statusSib; 
  $this -> jabatan = $jabatan;
  
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT appID FROM application WHERE (studID = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($studID) . "')");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
  {
   $appID = $row['appID'];
   $sql = "INSERT INTO `sibling`(`nameSib`, `jobSib`, `relationshipSib`, `age`, `statusSib`, `jabatan`, `appID`) 
     VALUES ('$nameSib', '$jobSib', '$relationshipSib', '$age', '$statusSib', '$jabatan', '$appID')";
   $query2 = mysql_query($sql);
   if(!$query2)
    echo mysql_error();
  }
  
  
 }
```

Comment: The error message is your answer and if you search at google with your error you will find lots of result.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your variable:

```
$a = new application();

...

        foreach($nameSib as $a => $b)
                            ^^ here
        {
```

You need to use a different variable name for your loop:

```
        foreach($nameSib as $key => $value)
        {
```

Comment: didnt realize about it. when i change it, and submit 3 data, only one in database. how do i do so all 3 can be insert to database?

Comment: @mimisya You need to narrow down the problem and probably ask a new question. Could be anything, like sql injecting yourself, the POST values not being arrays, etc..

Comment: @jereon cant understand it, first time using php to develop system :(